# Spring JPA - How to rollback multiple services with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jpa, service, transactions

We have a controller that calls a lot of services, which one has a @Transaction annotation.
Thats a problem because if we have any errors in one of those services we dont have rollback of all of them.

Is there another annotation that help to handle it?
or should i remove @transaction from services and move it to controller?

Comment: Write another service that encompasses those methods which is `@Transactional`. Don't make your controller transactional. If you are calling more than 1 service method in your controller you are doing to much in your method (IMHO and as a rule of thumb).